# Vue2 component rendering on ajax response

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a component that reacts to this template:

```
<table-sort index="job.job_id"></table-sort>
```

However, when I get this template from a ajax response and add it to the DOM. It doesn't recognize it as a Vue component. How do I render this component?

Here is my component:

```
Vue.component('table-sort', {
    name: 'table-sort',
    template: `
        <div class="table-sort" :data-index="index">
            <i v-on:click="sortTable($event)" direction="ASC" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
            <i v-on:click="sortTable($event)" direction="DESC" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
    `,
    props: {
        index: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        sortTable: function ($event) {
            const self      = $event.target;
            const index     = this.index;
            const direction = self.getAttribute('direction');

            let filters       = Url.getQueryParameters();
            filters.sort      = index;
            filters.direction = direction;
            filters.page      = 1;

            const url    = Url.getUrlWithoutQueryString();
            const newUrl = Url.appendParamsToUrl(filters, url);
            Url.redirect(newUrl);
        },
    },
});
```

Here is how I call the code to generate the table:

```
var ajaxTable = new AjaxTable({
        name: 'jobs',
        request: inputs,
        container: '#job-table',
        fields: fields,
    });
```

Here is the code that appends the template:

```
public async drawTable() {
    this.table = $(`<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed"><thead><tr id="header"></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>`);
    this.count = $(`<div class="count pull-left"></div>`);
    this.pagination = $(`<div class="pagination pull-right"></div>`);

    this.fields.map((field: ColumnData) => {
        let out = `<th>${field.title}`;
        if (!!field.sort) {
            out += ` <table-sort index="${field.sort}"></table-sort>`;
        }
        out += `</th>`;


        this.table.find('#header').append(out);
    });

    this.container.append(this.table, this.count, this.pagination);
}
```

Comment: What error you get? How you add it to the dom? Where is your component included?

Comment: If Vue was instantiated before this was rendered then it wont see it.  It sounds like you're using jQuery or some other ajax method to load content that includes Vue templates - Consider using Vue from the get go so your `table-sort` component can be there from the start, and use `v-if="ajaxLoaded"` or something to show up

Comment: I don't get an error. It just doesn't render. I add it to the DOM using jquery, specifically using $(ele).append(`<table-sort index="${field.sort}"></table-sort>`);

Comment: @Jeff can you please more information on how to do that? I dont' fully understand what you mean.

Comment: You need to post the code that is making the Ajax call and the html you're entering it into

Comment: @Jeff, okay, I added the code.